# Linux ModuleNotFoundError after installing python module

Tags: python, python-3.x, linux, python-2.7, pip

I'm getting this:

```
No module named 'pandas'
```

Although I did this:

```
pip install pandas
```

`whereis python` shows this:

```
python: /usr/bin/python2.7-config /usr/bin/python2.7
/usr/bin/python3.6m-config /usr/bin/python3.6m /usr/bin/python3.6
/usr/bin/python /usr/bin/python3.6-config /usr/lib/python3.7
/usr/lib/python2.7 /usr/lib/python3.6 /etc/python2.7 /etc/python3.6
/etc/python /usr/local/lib/python2.7 /usr/local/lib/python3.6
/usr/include/python2.7 /usr/include/python3.6m /usr/include/python3.6
/usr/share/python /usr/share/man/man1/python.1.gz
```

That is a lot of info. Is that a problem?

Comment: `pip install pandas --user` try this maybe?

Comment: open command prompt as an administrator and then install pandas via pip

Comment: psn1997,  Noufal Ibrahim does not agree (see comment to first answer). Sahil, did not work.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

at first, execute the upgrade

```
sudo pip3 install --upgrade pip
```

then install the pandas as "root"(administrator).

```
sudo pip3 install pandas
```

Comment: I wouldn't recommend `sudo` for doing this. The correct way would be to use a `virtualenv` or use the `--user` for a user wide install.

Comment: needed pip3, not pip